# WebView wont copy the text in Windows 10 mobile

Tags: webview, copy-paste, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows 8.1 application which I am trying to run on Windows 10 mobile. I have a control which renders html data using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView However when I tap on some text on the webview the copy button appears, when I tap copy button it does not copy the content of the webview (Because when I try and paste the content somewhere else, it still pastes the old content which I copied earlier). Same flow works fine on WP8.1

I cannot put any sample code here since I am not sure what would be relevant. Just wanted to check if someone else ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one sample WP 8.1 application to simply load the string content in a webview control. It looks like this is an issue with webview control. Since I am facing the same issue with the sample application as well.
Below is the sample code:
In MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WebView Name="WebView"></WebView>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="TextBox"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

In MainPage.caml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebView.NavigateToString("This is a test application to test webview control.");
}
```